# Dynamic Category thematic map

Tags: qgis, classification, visualisation, thematic-map

I am working in QGIS 3.8.3-Zanzibar on a shapefile with polygons.

I am zoning by selecting the polygons and giving each group a different number (a zone code).

In order to visualize it, I have a Category Thematic map with the zone number, so I can easily see the different groups I am creating.

[image: zoning progress]

But, as I keep on making groups (that is, giving other zone codes to the polygons), it is hard to visualize the result unless I manually update the thematic map.

**I would like the map to dynamically change its colours as I change the zone numbers**. Until now, I have to re-classify the categories of the thematic map, as it only classifies with the existing numbers (zone codes) but the new ones I give out, the all go to the group of "all other..."

[image: categories and "all other..."]

---

Here I am going to show my work routine with sample data, as suggested:

1. Initial shapefile with polygons. Visualization is simple symbol.

[image: 1]

2. Visualization with a Category thematic map depending on the zone number (last column of my table).

[image: 2]

3. I select some polygons and change their zone number.

[image: 3]

4. The visualization has change according to the new zone number of the polygons.

[image: 4]

5. I then change other polygons zone number.

[image: 5]

6. The visualization changes again, but with the same colour, because any other zone numbers are classified as “all other”.

[image: 6]

7. I would like to have this visualization without having to manually  update the categories of the thematic map.

[image: 7]

I don't know how to upload shapefiles, in order to provide the sample data, but here it is a screenshot of my table (it really only matters the last column).

[image: Table]

Comment: I tried to explain the routine better, but I don't know how to provide shapefiles. I hope the new images help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is range of the zone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be like this:

- In Style Panel, type `$id` for "Value".
- Click on "Classify" button. This generates separate symbols for each id.
- Change `$id` to  `ZoneID`.
- Now, there is a color for each zone id. I assume that the range of ZoneIDs is the same of the feature ids. You may need to refresh map canvas (F5) to see the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid manually updating the categories, simply click the `Classify` button each time you made a change:

[image]

Comment: If I do that, I get the same colour as before, plus I was trying to avoid the manually click (I have many zones to change). I was hoping there was some sort of dynamic update of the thematic map.

Comment: This should be possible using PyQgis - however, due to the policy of this site, questions asking for Python should include some code attempts.